# Cypress API testing : How to login and then use the auth token in another test?

Tags: javascript, api-testing, cypress

How can I access the token generated from 1st `it` block to 2nd `it` block.

here is the code:

1st it block

```
      it('Login using new user', () => {
        cy.api({
          method: "POST",
          url:    "https://api-stg.sample.com/v1/user/login",
          body: 
          {
          "mobile_number": "+9912345678"
          "password": "p@ssword"  
          }

        })
          .then((response) => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
        })
          .then((response) => {
            const bearer_token = response.body.data.user.access_token.token // 
*in here where I get and put the token in var bearer_token*

            cy.log("Bearer token: " + token )
        })
      })
```

2nd it block

```
     it('Create New Mobile', () => {
        cy.api({
          method: "POST",
          url:    "https://api-stg.sample.com/v1/user/add_new_mobile_numbers",
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token // *in here where I put the token*
          },
          body: 
          {
            "mobile_prefix": "+991",
            "mobile_number": "9912345679"
          }
})
```

I login from 1st block, then i need to use the token to add new mobile num in 2nd block.
in cypress dashboard it returns an error:
`token is not defined`

Comment: I'd suggest reading https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases, but also note your tests should be _independent_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the login outside the test, for example, to a before.

You may need to add a condition where it checks if token exists already.

You may also be able to use a before all depending on language and framework.

To use across test files you may wish to consider doing the login in the test runner and setting the token in a way that the framework will expose to individual tests.

As Jon suggested, react the Cypress documentation - it is very good!